# Dynamic width and height of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to have a image-group of three images. Every single image has to have the same, dynamic height and the image-group has to use 100% of the size of it's parent div (so margin-left of the first image is the same as margin-right of the last image)

Basically what I need is a CSS or JS solution, which is fully dynamic.

My goal: [Width, height and if possible margin between images should be dynamic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZ90.jpg)

What I have so far:

```css
.img-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
 float: left;
 margin: 4%; /*Margin should, but doesn't have to be dynamic...*/
 height: 20%; /*Height has to be dynamic...*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg/1024px-Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg.png">
    <img class="img" src="http://lofrev.net/wp-content/photos/2017/03/4k_ultra_hd_logo.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="http://hometheaterreview.com/4K-HDR-logo-thumb.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are your source images of the same aspect ratio or size?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 4%; /*Margin should, but doesn't have to be dynamic...*/ /*Height has to be dynamic...*/
  max-height: 30px;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg/1024px-Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg.png">
    <img class="img" src="http://lofrev.net/wp-content/photos/2017/03/4k_ultra_hd_logo.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="http://hometheaterreview.com/4K-HDR-logo-thumb.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I completely understand what you are trying to accomplish but here is my attempt at answering.

You can edit the height of the  style and the images and the img-group dive expand accordingly.

I put the borders around the elements to see the "space" of each element. You can remove them from the styles.

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.img-group {
  height: 97.5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid purple;
}

.img {
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  /*Margin should, but doesn't have to be dynamic...*/
  height: 40%;
  /*Height has to be dynamic...*/
  border: 4px solid green;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg/1024px-Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg.png">
    <img class="img" src="http://lofrev.net/wp-content/photos/2017/03/4k_ultra_hd_logo.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="http://hometheaterreview.com/4K-HDR-logo-thumb.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image are always the same and of a known size, you need to set the width so they can fill up the whole row and be sized to the same height.

***Snippet CSS commented.***

```css
.container {
  width:80%;/* whatever*/
  margin:auto;
  border:solid;/* see me */
  overflow:hidden;/* wraps float*/
  /* or use :
  display:flex;
  */
}
img {
  float:left;/* unless parent is set to display:flex;,but it will be a fallback for old browsers*/
  width:20.1%;/* the smallest, others will be reset */      
}
img[src*="Logo.svg.png"] {
  width:52.1%;/* obviously the widest*/
}
img[src*="logo.jpg"] {
  width:27.77%;/* the other one */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-group">
    <img class="img" src="http://lofrev.net/wp-content/photos/2017/03/4k_ultra_hd_logo.jpg"/>
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg/1024px-Digital_Europe_Ultra_HD_-_Logo.svg.png"/>
    <img class="img" src="http://hometheaterreview.com/4K-HDR-logo-thumb.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```